# Ext JS layout crash when moving panle to external class

Tags: javascript, layout, extjs, extjs4.1

This is my first big project in Ext JS so please by understandable :) 
I'm building an application based on portal example. What I need to create is simple layout with toolbar on top, statusbar on bottom and tabpanel taking whole screen. Like so:
[image: layout]

Basic idea is to have every big control in separate file, so that it will be easy to change some part of application.

My directory structure looks like so:

```
root
--layout.html
--js
----App.js
----Components
------StatusBar.js
------UserInfo.js
------MenuBar
--------UserMenuBar.js
------Dashboard
--------UserDashboard.js
```

My App.js looks like this:

```
Ext.ns('Holidays');

Ext.Loader.setConfig({
enabled: true,
disableCaching: true
});

Ext.Loader.setPath('Holidays', 'js');
Ext.Loader.setPath('Holidays.Components', 'js/Components');
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', 'js/ux');

Holidays.application = null;

Ext.application({
name: "Holidays",
launch: function () {
    Holidays.application = this;
    this.createLayout();
    Holidays.application = this;
    Ext.fly(document.body).on('contextmenu', this.onContextMenu, this);
},
onContextMenu: function (e, target) {
    if (!e.ctrlKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
},

createLayout: function () {

    this.menuBar = Ext.create("Holidays.Components.MenuBar.UserMenuBar");
    this.statusBar = Ext.create("Holidays.Components.StatusBar");
    this.centerView = Ext.create("Holidays.Components.Dashboard.UserDashboard");

    this.centerPanel = Ext.create("Ext.tab.Panel", {
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        border: false,
        region: 'center',
        bodyStyle: 'background:#DBDBDB',
        plugins: Ext.create('Ext.ux.TabCloseMenu')

    });

    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            border: false,
            layout: 'border',
            items: [
            this.centerPanel],
            bbar: this.statusBar,
            tbar: this.menuBar
        }]

    });

    this.addItem(this.centerView);
},

addItem: function (item) {
    this.centerPanel.add(item);
    item.show();
},

getStatusbar: function () {
    return this.statusBar;
},

getCenterView: function () {
    return this.centerView;
}
});

Holidays.getApplication = function () {
return Holidays.application;
};
```

and Dashboard.js looks like so:

```
Ext.define('Holidays.Components.Dashboard.UserDashboard', {
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
alias: 'widget.UserDashboard',
layout: 'border',
padding: 5,
closable: false,
title: 'Holiday planner',
initComponent: function () {

    this.tree = Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel", {
        region: 'west',
        split: true,
        title: 'Categories',
        width: 300,
        collapsible: true,
        animCollapse: false
    });

    //this.tree = Ext.create("Holidays.Components.UserInfo");THIS WON'T WORK :(


    this.grid = Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel", {
        title: 'Plan urlopu',
        region: 'center',
        split: true,
    });

    this.history = Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel", {
        collapsed: true,
        collapsible: true,
        region: 'east',
        split: true,
        width: 300,
        animCollapse: false,
        title: 'test'
    });

    this.items = [this.tree, this.grid, this.history];

    this.callParent();
},

getScheduler: function () {
    return this.grid;
}
});
```

If I move left panel to external file I my layout crashes-panel shouldn't have animation when collapsing and when I collapse it and try to restore my toolbar and statusbar vanish :/

Here is my code: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1206389/layout.zip

My question are:

1. How to create a layout and separate parts to external files?
2. Do I must create alias for every controll? What are the benefits?
3. How to use Ext.Loader to correct load components on demand (parts of interface in my case)
4. How to add statusbar and toolbar to Viewport? Am I doing it right?

And finally is my layout correct? Any advices are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Your bars vanish when `animCollapse: true` is set. This behavior not depends on configuration type. Try to enable it in the embedded one and bars will crash.

1. see [Application Architecture](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/application_architecture) topic
2. no, you don't. `alias: 'widget.blah'` is just a simple shorthand for `xtype: 'blah'` and `Ext.widget('blah')`
3. Loader by defaults do it for you
4. just put a panel inside the center of the viewport, set its layout to `border`, configure child items and use [tbar](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-tbar) / [bbar](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-bbar) of itself

Comment: so I can't use animCollapse: true? I know that I'm not using strict MVC architecture, but how should i fix my layout? :)

Comment: Mmm, I think you should try to rewrite your layout completely. I have never seen such strange behavior, usually it works fine.

Comment: The weirdest part is that when I put everything in one file it works just fine, cutting it apart creates my problem. I'll try to recreate whole thing second time, probably it's tiny mistake :)